# How to choose the right version of Google Cloud library components in python?

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a specific version of google-cloud-core in my server and I don’t know how to choose the other libraries in a way to make them suit with my google cloud core version.

I can’t just move to the latest versions because old programs cannot run into new versions for example BigQuery library.
My specific need is to know « how to know » which version of Google Cloud Storage should I choose according to the 0.26.0 core version.

Is there some repositories where we can find packages grouped by google-cloud-core versions? 
In my case the version 1.6 of google-cloud-storage works but I found it just by downgrade and try again method !

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do as a workaround is create a virtual environment, install a specific library - like `google-cloud-storage` - and check the dependencies installed with that library version. I made a quick test and installed a few versions of google-cloud-storage. For version 1.3.0, the `google-cloud-core 0.26.0` dependency was installed.

You can do so by following these steps:

```
virtualenv env-name
source env-name/bin/activate
pip freeze (to check there is nothing there)
pip install google-cloud-storage==1.3.0
pip freeze (again)
```

Once finished you’ll see google-cloud-core 0.26.0 was installed.